# Displaying HTML in Odoo 16 reports

Tags: odoo, odoo-16, odoo-enterprise

There is a field 'note' in the 'sale.order' module, in it I want to write HTML code(`<h1>TITLE</h1>`), and output the title, but in the report instead of the title I get just the text `<h1>TITLE</h1>`
I tried doing it through t-raw, but it doesn't work, also tried it throughout, it still doesn't work[image]

p.s. I use the Odoo studio editor

Comment: This should be simple to fix but I will need to dig into more details and try different approaches in order to get a solution. Reach me if you need this really solved